# Como substituir caracteres de uma String?

Tags: java, string, formatação

Estou com um pequeno problema. Minha aplicação recebe do servidor uma String numérica representando um valor. Mas o servidor manda, por exemplo `"100.00"` e eu preciso colocar uma vírgula no lugar desse ponto.

`100.00` => `100,00`

Gostaria de saber como fazer isso da maneira mais simples possível. Fuçei tutoriais por aí que não me ajudaram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma opção "simples" é utilizar o método `replace` da classe [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)).

```
String valorComPonto = "100.00";
String valorComVirgula = valorComPonto.replace('.', ',');
```

Comment: É isso aí mesmo. Não achei nada que me ajudasse na NET e fui lendo os métodos da classe String. Obrigado, cara! Eu deveria ter prestado mais atenção, mas mesmo assim obrigado. =D

Aceitarei a resposta ASAP